# Bootbox modal scrolls to top of page before opening

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootbox, gsap

I am using bootstrap 3 and bootbox.js for my filterable portfolio, and I want to be able to scroll down when a modal is longer than the browser window, but you should not be able to scroll past the modal.

By default when you click a portfolio item the modal would scroll to the top of the page to open it. I used `javascript:void(0);` on my portfolio links to fix this. but `position:absolute` on `.modal` breaks that.

But `position:absolute` and `overflow:auto` allows me to scroll the modal the way I need (just dont know how to limit scrolling till the end of the modal)

**Check out my css:**

```
.modal {
top: 10%;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -280px;
-webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
-moz-background-clip: padding-box;
background-clip: padding-box;
outline: none;
display: table;
position: absolute;
}

.modal-open {
overflow: auto;
}
```

[***You can look at the live version of my site here***](http://aliensix.com/lightningbolt/) *(scroll to portfolio and click a project)*

I have set up a fiddle to make it easier for everyone: http://jsfiddle.net/p4Yw2/

**So I need:**

1. Another way to fix the "scroll to the top before alert is opened"
   issue besides `javascript:void(0);`
2. A way to limit the scrolling until a little bit after the modal
       (right now you can scroll all the way down the page when the modal
       is open)

***UPDATE: Ok so what is causing this issue is my smooth-scroll.js file which consists of:***

```
$(function(){   

var $window = $(window);
var scrollTime = 0.7;
var scrollDistance = 275;

$window.on("mousewheel DOMMouseScroll", function(event){

    event.preventDefault(); 

    var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
    var finalScroll = scrollTop - parseInt(delta*scrollDistance);

    TweenMax.to($window, scrollTime, {
        scrollTo : { y: finalScroll, autoKill:true },
            ease: Power1.easeOut,
            overwrite: 5                            
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: Could you put together the code in a jsfiddle, so we can more easily offer changes/suggestions?

Comment: Have you considered setting the href to the id of the modal?  Then in the JS use preventDefault()?  In theory, without your additional styles to modal, Bootstrap should not scroll the body at all, only the content of the modal.

Comment: Ok I have set up a fiddle to make it easier for everyone http://jsfiddle.net/p4Yw2/

Comment: @davidpauljunior any chance you can demonstrate this? I read about using preventDefault() to solve this but I couldn't figure out where to put it in my situation and would I just target the default .modal class from bootstrap?

Comment: I was thinking that the Modal html was in the page already, I didn't realise Bootbox appends it to the page.  Not sure if you really need Bootbox here anyway?  You could load your modal contents remotely with the default Bootstrap code? E.g. `<a href="http://jsbin.com/koheq/1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal" id="branding1">`.  Try this JSBin (http://jsbin.com/yepec/1/edit), there's no Bootbox or additional JS.  This allows you to have your modal contents as separate files.

Comment: @davidpauljunior actually you are totally right! I ended up using the default bootstrap modal. If you want to post an answer and help with a small issue I ran into Ill give you the bounty! If you look at the live site you can see i did it the same way as you but there is still an issue with the scrolling, it is a little better but now the scroll bar shows up but when you scroll with the mouse wheel it scrolls the background still. But the viewport is limited on the modal scrolling I just need a way to cancel out the background scrolling so to speak.

Comment: @ve1jdramas Great, I've added an answer and in the mean time am looking into that scroll issue.

Comment: @ve1jdramas - Interestingly, if you add 'overflow: hidden' to the body before the modal is launched (via Inspector), you're still able to scroll which is odd (i.e. overflow isn't being hidden).  Try removing you're scroll scripts ('scroll-link', 'smooth-scroll', 'scrolltoplugin', 'skrollr', 'go-skrollr' etc) and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: @davidpauljunior ok you were totally right! the smooth-scroll.js is whats causing the issue! Now im trying to fix it but I cant get it for some reason! If you mind taking a look I added the JS in the question

Comment: @ve1jdramas I personally find scripts that interfere with how I use the mouse wheel really annoying and intrusive.  Perhaps consider using this smooth scroll from CSS tricks which just animates nicely when you click links and the page scrolls to the target. http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/

Comment: @davidpauljunior I actually already have that as well, I wanted to add something a little extra (I know its a little slow right now I was going to adjust it accordingly) but anyway if you want to give it a shot I'll give you the bounty end of today if you come up with something or not :) you've been a great help! I'm going to try some other ways to do see if I cant figure out something else. I really hate the default scrolling lol just want to clean it up a little

Comment: @ve1jdramas - Ah right I didn't realise you already had that.  To be honest I'm not a JS expert so working out what's causing the issue with your script above is a bit over me.  You may do well to take that snippet and ask a new question to find out why is causes the conflict in Bootstrap.  I did notice if you put that script in JSBin it gives you this error: `Line 12: var finalScroll = scrollTop - parseInt(delta*scrollDistance); --- Missing radix parameter.`  Not sure if that helps you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't *need* Bootbox (based on requirements in this question it seems overkill) then what you want sounds like what Bootstrap offers out of the box with it's modal loading remote content.  You can have all your different modal 'contents' store as individual pages and then have each link point to a different piece of modal content.  E.g:

`<a href="path_to_remote_content" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal" id="branding1">`.

This technique would require you to have the empty modal code in your page already, and then the contents are loaded into the `.modal-content`.

**Modal HTML for page**

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Remote content HTML**

```
<div class="modal-header">
  <h4>Beach Me</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  ...
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>
```

You'll need to remove all of the styles you've added that override Bootstrap's modal styles.

**[Demo](http://jsbin.com/yepec/1/edit)**

Comment: Just a note: this feature is deprecated, and won't exist in Bootstrap 4: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-options

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. Bootbox is changing the overflow of the body to hidden, making the page small so that it cannot be scrolled.

This css solved it for me:

```
body.modal-open {
    overflow: visible;
}
```

Comment: This works. The page does shift just a tiny bit, but at least it's not scrolled all the way to the top anymore.

Answer (score 0):

*`<a>` tag to add a class to handle all*

jquery

```
$('.modal-section').click(function() {
      $('section').css("display",'none');
}
```

or

```
$('#branding1').click(function() {
            $('section').css("display",'none');
            bootbox.alert('/*you html*/');
                  });

$('#print3').click(function() {
           $('section').css("display",'none');
            bootbox.alert('/*you html*/');
                  });
```

and button close modal:

```
   $('section').css("display",'block');
```

Comment: I gave this a shot but it did not change anything.

Comment: It seems to be working for me, there are various elements on the page that require jQuery to function

Comment: then there is something that prevents the execution of my code that should work

Comment: I am trying to set this up but im still not getting any results is there anyway you can edit the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p4Yw2/) so I can see exactly how you did it?

Comment: first `$('#branding1').click(function(){$('section').css("display",'none');});`

Comment: Wont that break bootbox altogether, you want me to replace this `$('#branding1').click(function() { bootbox.alert(` with `$('#branding1').click(function(){$('section').css("display",'none');});` this? I'm just confused 100% now

Comment: no, just add the code  `$('#branding1').click(function() { $('section').css("display",'none'); bootbox.alert('/*you html*/'); });`

Comment: and button close modal: add `$('section').css("display",'block');`